# Tracking the coordinates of the mouse click in flash

Tags: flash, click

I have a flash banner that redirects the user to a specific location. This isn't crucial to the development, but is it possible to track where exactly it's clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The MouseEvent has localX / localY and stageX / stageY properties.

Local is relative to the containing object and stage is relative to the global stage.

Docs: http://adobe.ly/1iSzi8J

Answer (score 0):

write the following code on mouseClick.

```
trace(stage.mouseX);
trace(stage.mouseY);
```